# Select all distinct values of variable in object array using lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I have an array of objects with the property of `ProductId`. I would like to use a lambda expression to select all the distinct values of `ProductId` that are within my object array `products`.

Here I get the products

```
var products = Database.SqlQuery<StructuredProduct>("query").ToArray();
```

And I can group by distinct values of ProductId, but it still returns an array of objects, rather than an array of ProductIds

```
var productIds= products.GroupBy(p => p.ProductId).Select(group => group.First()).ToArray();
```

Any idea on how to use a Lambda Expression on the `products` array to get all distinct values of `ProductIds`?

Comment: This looks a little scary, like the `Database.SqlQuery()` method will force you to write code that's crazy-vulnerable to sql injection issues. I hope there is a mechanism to accept query parameter data separate from sql command string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var productIds= products.Select(p => p.ProductId).Distict();
```

But it may be even better to do this directly on the database, as part of the `"query"` sql command.

Comment: var productIds= products.GroupBy(p => p.ProductId).Select(group => group.First()).Select(p=>p.ProductId).ToArray();

will also work. But above solution is better

Comment: This worked perfect thank you! I added a .ToArray() at the end and it was exactly what I needed. Unfortunately I can't include it in the ```"query"``` sql command due to some other limitations.

Comment: @LRID Adding .ToArray() is usually a **bad idea**. Instead, define your variable as an IEnumerable

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Never using `ToArray()` is an even worse idea, because you should not leave lazy sequences allocated if you know they will be fully enumerated. The consequence is repeatedly re-evaluating your collection, and risking side-effects (I've accidentally created access counters when generating class instances using LINQ), and thus keeping things in scope to the garbage collector. Operations such as `Sort()` and `Distinct()` mostly coerce full evaluation anyway, since how can you know if a value in set 1 is not in set 2 without scanning it completely?

Answer (score 4):

With LINQ method [.Distinct()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8)

```
var productIds = products.Select(p => p.ProductId).Distinct();
```

Comment: 17 seconds :) .

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn i’m compiled with optimization: on :D

Answer (score 1):

I've only ever done GroupBy operations with the query comprehension syntax.  If you do that, `group` / `by` / `into`, the thing you group into has a property named `key`.  That would contain your 'productid`

```
var results = from product in products
    group product by ProductId
    into individualProducts
    select individualProducts;

var productsArray = individualProducts.Select(p => p.Key).ToArray();
```

The items `individualProducts` collection each have a `Key` and a collection of things that have the same productid.

If you do this directly out of the database, all your operations will get nicely combined into a single SQL statement that will get executed when your code gets to `.ToArray()`